# Modify cloudera manager port 7180 to 80

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

My server offered by boss can access by port `80`.

How can I configure the Web UI port `7180` to `80`?

It doesn't work that I modified the `server_port` in `/etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini`

I can't access the UI, so the following does not work:

[Cloudera Server Ports](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cm_ag_cm_server_ports.html)

I need configure it in config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have strong belief that you should **NOT** change this port. It's possible in general, however you may meet some issues like those one in your case.

I can suggest you to use reverse proxy server such as [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) or Apache. It's much safer and maybe even faster.

So as result I'll get the following proxying chain which is fully transparent to clients:

- Client (your Boss) connects to server via port 80
- Nginx (or Apache) is listening port 80
- Nginx sends HTTP requests to Cloudera on port 7180
- Nginx returns request result to client (your Boss)